# FoxH function format implementation issue

Tags: special-functions, formatting

I am trying to code a particular Fox-H function in Mathematica,
$H_{2,2}^{2,0}\left(z\left| \begin{array}{c}(1,1),(1,\alpha)\\(1,1),(1,2)\\\end{array} \right.\right)$. I've been trying to use the format provided by the [FoxH](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html) Wolfram Documentation page.

The best I have been able to do is get $H_{2,2}^{0,0}\left(z\left| \begin{array}{c}(1,1),(1,\alpha)\\(1,1),(1,2)\\\end{array} \right.\right)$ using the Mathematica code:

```
FoxH[{{}, {{1, 1}, {1, \[Alpha]}}}, {{}, {{1, 2}, {1, 1}}}, z] // TraditionalForm
```

The TraditionalForm command allows you to see how Mathematica is reading your input, so this is a good check. Note that this function only differs in that I need m = 2, and get it only to m = 0 (see Mathematica Fox-H webpage for details).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Should n not be 2 instead of 0 for your case? Then H reads: `H[{{{1, 1}, {1, \[Alpha]}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}}, z]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FoxH[{{}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}, {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {}}, 
  z] // TraditionalForm
```

---

[image]

By the way, `TeXForm` fails on `FoxH` on version 13.0.1

```
TeXForm[FoxH[{{}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}, {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {}}, z]]
```

Comment: `TeXForm` fails on `FoxH` on version `14.0.0` to. It's a Bug.

Comment: Thanks, azerbajdzan, it worked. Also appreciate you raising the TeXForm issue and Mariusz providing the reason why it's not working. Cheers!